# How does google know what pages to crawl when using GatsbyJS

Tags: reactjs, seo, gatsby, google-crawlers

Pardon my lack of knowledge here, I am still new to using GatsbyJS.

When building out locally if I hit a 404 page I get a list of available pages. (see attached)

Just wondering if google indexes all these pages?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO, not programming. SEO questions may be asked on [Webmasters.SE](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google most likely will if it can see links to them and you don't have noindex hints or `Disallow` rule that affects them in `robots.txt`. Your best bet is to use [gatsby-plugin-sitemap](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-sitemap/) to generate a sitemap.xml . That you can submit to google and others.

Comment: Thanks Legend!!!